# Apache does not rewrite request if file on path exists

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm doing a rewrite with mod_rewrite on every request that does not match an existing file or directory. This is my configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

This is used to map URLs like `/abc/foo` or `/abc/foo/10` to my app. And it works just fine.

To improve the performance, my app now stores the results of a call to `/abc/foo` in a file `foo` in the corresponding directory `/abc` - so that after the first call the rewrite conditions do no longer apply (file does not exist) and apache directly serves the data without first invoking the app. Works fine as well.

The problem is: Requesting `/abc/foo/10` does now no longer cause the URL to get rewritten, instead I get an error "404 File Not Found". The log entries state that the rewrite condition `!-f` is no longer true, but actually the file `/abc/foo/10` does *not* exist. `/abc/foo` exists, but is a file, not a directory.

How can I get this to work?

(MultiViews is disabled)

Comment: Let me get this correct, So when you make a request `/abc/foo/10`, you want the data also to be written to the folder under /abc  under foo to  a file called 10? Is this what are you expecting even in the second call?

Comment: No, the problem is that if the file `/abc/foo` exists, a call to `/abc/foo/10` does not longer match `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`.

Comment: Why don't you put `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` first and then `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and see the result and also make the rewrite rule ^(.*)$ instead of ^.*$ and point it directly to index.php instead of /index.php

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, but that didn't change anything ._.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be in per-dir/htaccess context w/ AcceptPathInfo on.

Therefore REQUEST_FILENAME matched the part that existed, and is not the same as REQUEST_URI.

Use the REQUEST_URI var if you don't care where the request was previously mapped in your rewritecond.

In per-vh context, these vars are always the same.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "AcceptPathInfo", would it help to deactivate it?

Answer (score 4):

This is because foo exists as a file and apache serves foo with the additional /10 passed as a query string. So, your application should write some additional code to the foo file, that also checks if a request includes some additional url component and then handle creation of the directory "foo" and the file 10.

Comment: Is there any chance to tell Apache not to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Project design is a little bit wrong - others already pointed out that it's not scallable - how could You cache a request to /abc/foo/10 if there is already a /abc/foo file?

Answer to that and to Your problem is usage of subfolders instead of files.

So instead of cache structure of:

```
/abc/foo
/abc/bar
 ...?
```

use:

```
/abc/index.html
/abc/foo/index.html
/abc/bar/index.html
/abc/foo/10/index.html
```

and each time create new directory with index.html

This time Apache would find out that there is /abc/foo folder but no /abc/foo/10 file in it, so RewriteCond will apply.

**edit**

You could also try a different way - to modify url with mod_rewrite, changing urls:

```
/abc/foo
/abc/bar
/abc/foo/10
```

to something like:

```
/cache/abc~foo
/cache/abc~bar
/cache/abc~foo~10
```

htaccess rules (roughly):

```
# redirecting to cache folder and removing last '/'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(abc|cde)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /cache/$1 [L]

# recursive replacing '/' with '~'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cache/.*/
RewriteRule cache/(.*)/(.*)$ /cache/$1~$2 [L]
```

Your standard htaccess rules should follow

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I refactored the whole caching system already, but was still curious why Apache behaves that way.